# How to use a table alias with a Union statement in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, derived-table, table-alias

In an unpivoting operation, I would like the following:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM [complex joins/where clause] As DerivedTable
UNION
SELECT A, B, D FROM DerivedTable
UNION
SELECT A, B, E FROM DerivedTable
...
```

but it complains that `DerivedTable` cannot be found (I use a derived table so that `[complex joins/where clause]` doesn't have to be evaluated again and again thereby slowing things).

I know I can simply create a new query called `DerivedTable` to represent `[complex joins/where clause]` but

- The above SQL is passed from Excel - I'd rather not have to open the database to create a new query prior to running the above
- The `[complex joins/where clause]` is generated dynamically, and changes from user to user, two of which may be running the above SQL at the same time.

Comment: That's not the way unions work, unfortunately. I assume you're restricted to a single query (rather than being able to output multiple SQL statements), so are you able to simply output `[complex joins/where clause]` in all unions, not just the first?

Comment: `[complex joins/where clause]` takes a long time to execute, so ideally I'd like to avoid repeated evaluation of `[complex joins/where clause]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Use CASE and JOIN this table with (1,2,3,...) table. I'm not sure it is right syntax for Access but it will work on most SQL dialects.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/01795/1)

```
SELECT A,B, 
       CASE WHEN CT.r=1 then C
            WHEN CT.r=2 then D
            WHEN CT.r=3 then E
       END

FROM [complex joins/where clause] As DerivedTable
CROSS JOIN (select 1 as r
            union all  
            select 2 as r
            union all  
            select 3 as r
           ) as CT
order by A,B
```